# Querying assets with filter returns too small subset of assets

Tags: c#, azure-media-services

I'm querying assets that have empty `alternateId`, but using the following code I only get around 7k assets. If I query without the filter and count the number of returned assets with empty `alternateId`, it is around 36k. It's not related to paging as I'm using the same `NextPageLink` paging logic in both test cases.

What could be the reason for this? I'm looking into optimizing the code by not having to get all 72k assets but only the ones with empty `alternateId`, and update that after having processed the asset.

I use `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media` v6.0.0.

```
var assets = await client.Assets.ListAsync(
    config.ResourceGroup,
    config.AccountName,
    new Microsoft.Rest.Azure.OData.ODataQuery<Asset>() { 
        Filter = "properties/alternateId eq ''" 
    }
);
```

Comment: try using `where` example :- `var assets = client.Assests.where( filter ).ToListAsync();`

Comment: I don't think that applies here at all.

Comment: how about native linq query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter by `properties/alternateId eq null` to get null values. If you want both null and empty values you can use `properties/alternateId eq '' or properties/alternateId eq null`

Here is some sample code to test out the behavior. I added an additional filter on created date to exclude old data.

```
            var alternateNull = await Client.Assets.CreateOrUpdateAsync(ResourceGroup, MediaAccount, "alternate_null", new Asset());
            var alternateEmpty = await Client.Assets.CreateOrUpdateAsync(ResourceGroup, MediaAccount, "alternate_empty", new Asset { AlternateId = "" });
            var alternateSet = await Client.Assets.CreateOrUpdateAsync(ResourceGroup, MediaAccount, "alternate_set", new Asset { AlternateId = "abcd" });

            var getNulls = await Client.Assets.ListAsync(
                ResourceGroup,
                MediaAccount,
                new Microsoft.Rest.Azure.OData.ODataQuery<Asset>()
                {
                    Filter = "properties/created gt 2022-10-07T00:00:00Z and properties/alternateId eq null"
                });

            Console.WriteLine("Nulls:");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', getNulls.Select(s => s.Name)));

            var getEmpty = await Client.Assets.ListAsync(
                ResourceGroup,
                MediaAccount,
                new Microsoft.Rest.Azure.OData.ODataQuery<Asset>()
                {
                    Filter = "properties/created gt 2022-10-07T00:00:00Z and properties/alternateId eq ''"
                });

            Console.WriteLine("Empty:");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', getEmpty.Select(s => s.Name)));

            var getNullOrEmpty = await Client.Assets.ListAsync(
                ResourceGroup,
                MediaAccount,
                new Microsoft.Rest.Azure.OData.ODataQuery<Asset>()
                {
                    Filter = "properties/created gt 2022-10-07T00:00:00Z and (properties/alternateId eq '' or properties/alternateId eq null)"
                });

            Console.WriteLine("Null Or Empty:");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', getNullOrEmpty.Select(s => s.Name)));

            var getAll = await Client.Assets.ListAsync(
                ResourceGroup,
                MediaAccount,
                new Microsoft.Rest.Azure.OData.ODataQuery<Asset>()
                {
                    Filter = "properties/created gt 2022-10-07T00:00:00Z"
                });

            Console.WriteLine("All:");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', getAll.Select(s => s.Name)));
```